# Utilizar Mídias no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Olá, bom dia. Tenho um áudio na pasta raw, com alguns segundos de duração. Eu quero utilizar esse áudio quando o aplicativo for aberto. Quando a aplicação for inicializada, ela já vai iniciar com o áudio tocando. Alguém me ajuda a fazer isso? Agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa apenas a classe [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) e usar o método `start()` para inicializar. Veja:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysoundfile);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

Para que o audio pare, bastar usar o método `stop()`. Abaixo segue um exemplo parar o áudio quando a aplicação for destruida. Veja:

```
public void onDestroy() {

    mPlayer.stop();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @AdlemElvis por nada! =)

Comment: Como eu aprendo sobre essas classes e métodos? Ou eu só vou aprender toda vez que perguntar pra alguém? por exemplo: se eu precisar exibir um pdf, como vou aprender a fazer isso? tem alguma coisa em algum lugar para estudar, ou vou ter que perguntar a alguém?

Comment: @AdlemElvis na documentação tem muita coisa. Mas caso queria algo em específico, pode perguntar por aqui mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado de novo!

Comment: Não achei essa opção. "Validar"

Comment: Pronto. Muito Obrigado pela paciência.